# Python: Mechanize

Tags: python, django, mechanize

My problem i very short and sweet that I'm using mechanize module to sign into a website, but how to find out that a user has successfully signed in or not. for eg.

```
br = open("http://xyz.com/signin")
br['login'] = xxxx
br['password'] = xxx
result = br.submit().read()
f  = open('s.html', 'w')
f.write(result)
f.close
```

Now if login information is true s.html will contain next redirected page, and if information is false it will contain error page. Now how to find out that username annd pasword are true for a user......thanks in advance

Comment: why are you saving the response in a file? you can just test the response variable after the read for the status code

Comment: can u explain more deeply, because i'm trying it for first time

Comment: you seem to be opening the file, you should be using br.open as detailed here: http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/

Comment: basically delete what you've got and start over with the link I just gave you.

Comment: thanks that help me....but using this signin method can I hack someones password whose username is known by writing a algo. which pass the possible combinations of passwords, and how ca i speed up this process

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the page content that you were served.

If it has the string

> login failed

Or similar then you know it failed.

Comment: but if i had thousands of such logins to do, then it'll become bit time wasting method....and also why can't i able to sign in to facebook, when i write br = open("http://www.facebook.com/") it gives some error

Comment: you've no choice but to check the returned page to see if the login worked or not. How else are you thinking you can do it?

Comment: since the login of facebook is in its main-page so i write it as the same way as http://www.facebook.com

Comment: The error is no doubt related to the robots.txt facebook are using. That can be fixed with br.set_handle_robots(False)

Answer (score 0):

It usually redirects to a different page if login is successful else it remains on the same page and an error message appears

You could use something like this

```
if br.geturl()==("https://address of the page after login"):
        print "SUCCESS"
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `br.geturl()`and check if it's the URL when you login or not. Let's say it's `xyz.com/welcome`.